# Additional <div>'s created when jquery is used for auto refresh

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have 3 `div`s having 3 distinct background & text prints on the `div`. Text on each block is refreshed automatically whenever the contents in `response.php` are modified.

**Problem**
Additional 2 `div`s are created as can be seen on screenshot.

**Objective**
I want to remove the additional `div`s.

My codes:

**CSS**

```
#container{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:cornflowerblue;
    color:white;
}
#container2{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:black;
    color:red;
}
#container3{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:brown;
    color:yellow;
}
```

**JS/jQuery**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#container").load("response.php");
     var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
         $("#container").load('response.php');
     }, 1000); 

     $("#container2").load("response.php");
     var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
         $("#container2").load('response.php');
     }, 1000);

     $("#container3").load("response.php");
     var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
         $("#container3").load('response.php');
     }, 1000);
     $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="container"></div><p>
    <div id="container2"></div><p>
    <div id="container3"></div>
</body></html><p>
```

**response.php**

```
 <?php  
    echo '<div id="container">1</div>';
    echo '<div id="container2">2</div>';
    echo '<div id="container3">3</div>';
 ?>
```

What can be done to achieve my objective? Is the way I used jQuery correct?

[image]

Comment: I think, this is expected behavior, You are loading **response.php** contens i.e. `3 divs` into all the other `3 div`. Hence, **3*3=9** divs..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao is right - in other words, every time you load "response.php", three new divs will be created. If all you want is to update the content, maybe you should have your PHP script return an array, then use the array to update the content of each div (using jQuery's .text() method, for example)

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour. **response.php** contains 3 `div`s which you are loading 3 times.
Hence 3 * 3 = 9.

Another way maybe to, instead of having 3 `div`s loaded on load of the php file. only have 1. However, I realise on that that you are not able to set the `id` as IDs are unique. Instead you can give them `class` attributes (i.e. `class="container"`). You would then be able to select individual ones via jQuery using `:nth-child()`. For example, if you want to select/reference the 2nd `div`, you can say: *(in jQuery)*

```
$(".container:nth-child(2)").on('click', function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because whenever you call .load('response.php'), there's 3 echos in it. And you called it thrice in a row.

Call it only once.
Try creating a parent class. 
Now you have a parent class with 3 containers in it.

Solution :
Always remove all the children and call 'response.php' with your parent.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this code. But i would say you question is 99% clear, could you also include the exact result you are looking for but till then you could try this code below for every container

```
$("#container").load("response.php");
     var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
         $("#container").empty().load('response.php');
     }, 1000);
```

One more thing I noticed, you are using id container,container2, container3 
and the structure of your result would be container[container, container2, container3] similarly for others, don't you think its too many same id's in a single HTML. Just an observation. you might want to use one unique ID for unique element